# Android JobScheduler not running period task on Vivo phone

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have a job scheduler designed to repeat every 20 minutes. I have tried it on nexus, one plus, moto E4 and Vivo. It seems do the periodic job roughly every 20 minutes in all these phones except on Vivo. On vivo the job runs only a couple of times and then never runs. 
I found out that phones like Vivo, Xiomi etc need to have auto start enabled. So, I enabled auto start and then tried to run the job. Again it runs onle for the first few times (2-3) and then it is never fired again.

This is the code

```
        val serviceComponent = ComponentName(context, BackupJobService::class.java)
        val builder = JobInfo.Builder(jobId, serviceComponent)
        builder.setPeriodic(20*60*1000L)
        val jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler::class.java)
        val job = builder.build()
        jobScheduler.schedule(job)
```